# Python MPI waiting for a process with communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I recently started to migrate my project from SCOOP to MPI using MPI4PY.

I use SCOOP to basically parallelise a for loop with a definition. I want the main process to wait for the other processes to finish (at the end i want to do something different, but for testing it is enough).

To achieve this i thought i will send a "message" like "ASD" frm every process after the finish, and collect it at the main process, and only continue of all has been received.

However for some reason i cant receive these messages.

What i wanted to do is:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import time


def func(arg, rank):
    startTime = time.time()
    for i in arg:
        print("Process %d: Took %f seconds for %s" % (rank, time.time() - startTime, i))
        comm.send("ASDASDASDAS", dest=0, tag=11)

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
my_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
if rank != 0:
    chunk_size = (len(my_lst) // size) + 1  # number of files this process will handle
    chunk = [x for x in range(rank * chunk_size, (rank + 1) * chunk_size)]  # Fix this line to
    func([my_lst[x] for x in chunk if x < len(my_lst)], rank)
elif rank == 0:
    for i in range(1,rank):
        a = comm.recv(source=i, tag=11)
        print(a)
    print("Parallel done")
```

I tried to simplify my problem, so if i start from the tutorials code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    comm.send(data, dest=1, tag=11)
elif rank == 1:
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
    print(data)
```

It works perfectly fine. However if i try to send from multiple processes to process 0 i dont see any output.

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank != 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    comm.send(data, dest=0, tag=11)
else:
    for i in range(1, rank):
        data = comm.recv(source=i, tag=11)
        print(data)
```

Why is this happening? Also if this "wait for a process to reach a certain point" thing can be done easier with something else please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rank `0` does not receive from any task because of an incorrect range.

try to replace

```
for i in range(1, rank):
```

with

```
size = comm.Get_size()
for i in range(1, size):
```

Comment: everyone needs an extra pair of eyes once in a while :-)

Comment: Yes it is. `MPI_Irecv()` is the non blocking version, but i do not remember how it is wrapped by `mpi4py`